# Mix two .NET frameworks in Windows Mobile 8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Windows Phone application with Visual Studio 2013 Premium.

I have an older version of this project built for the old Windows Mobile platform. 
The old project contains proxy classes used with the "Add Service Reference" functionality, ie classes and references from a WSDL file.

The new Visual Studio 2013 does not give the capability to add web service reference, unless you specify an older .NET framework.

My question is the following: Can I combine somehow the new UI capabilities with my old code?
Is it possible for a example to have a dll with the old web references (.NET 3.5) and link it with a project with target the "Windows Mobile 8"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 available APIs don't allow you to handle anything about connection parameters, so proxy address as well.

Comment: so the answer is "No"

Comment: Sure, I advise to wait for WP 8.1 developer preview to be out, maybe they have improved connection interface APIs